# How to autoadjust the height of a div if its height is specified?

Tags: html, css

I want the header height to adjust to show all elements if the window width is reduced, like on the first picture below - this is what I want. Unfortunately, since in the parent style that I have to use, the height of the div is specified (`height:90px`, I cannot remove this line), and the height does not get reduced, as on the second picture.

How could I cancel this `height:90px` line? The code is here: https://jsfiddle.net/qhk8uh3z/5/

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you cant remove the line, then simply override the height, use ´height:auto;´.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you add `height:auto;` to overide the previous hide set ??

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qhk8uh3z/6/)

```
/* my override */
#sidebar-header {
   min-height: 115px !important;
   height:auto;                   <--- Add this
   overflow: hidden;
   width:100%;
}
```